# Loading a tga/bmp file in C++/OpenGL

Tags: c++, image, file, opengl, loading

I'm trying to load a tga/bmp file. This works fine, but the end result looks like this:

[image]

The image I'm trying to load looks like this:

[image]

Some of the code I'm using:

```
GLuint texture;
const char* filename = "/Users/Admin/Documents/Visual Studio 2013/Projects/OpenGL/OpenGL/image.tga";

unsigned char* data;
data = (unsigned char *) malloc(128 * 128 * 3);
FILE* f;
fopen_s(&f, filename, "rb");
fread(data, 128 * 128 * 3, 1, f);

glGenTextures(1, &texture);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);

glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, 128, 128, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
```

Does anybody have an idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: tga files have a header don't they? It looks like you are expecting it to be a 128x128 pixel raw. I don't know why you would expect that to work.

Comment: Just wondering, but if you're using C++ then why are you using `malloc()` ?

Comment: I saw that on another tutorial. I tried different things, for example using malloc(), but the result didnt change

Comment: Adding to what @Tim had said: TGA files do not only have a header, they also support different data formats (number of channels, palettes), a varying offset where the image data can start, RLE compression, different origin setups and so forth. The above code will never load any image format correctly, it just assumes raw dumps of a certain format.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can load a bitmap and a tga file using these..

```
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>

#ifdef __APPLE__
#include <OpenGL/gl.h>
#include <OpenGL/glu.h>
#endif


#ifdef _WIN32
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glu.h>
#endif


typedef union PixelInfo
{
    std::uint32_t Colour;
    struct
    {
        std::uint8_t B, G, R, A;
    };
} *PPixelInfo;


class BMP
{
private:
    std::uint32_t width, height;
    std::uint16_t BitsPerPixel;
    std::vector<std::uint8_t> Pixels;

public:
    BMP(const char* FilePath);
    std::vector<std::uint8_t> GetPixels() const {return this->Pixels;}
    std::uint32_t GetWidth() const {return this->width;}
    std::uint32_t GetHeight() const {return this->height;}
    bool HasAlphaChannel() {return BitsPerPixel == 32;}
};

BMP::BMP(const char* FilePath)
{
    std::fstream hFile(FilePath, std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
    if (!hFile.is_open()) throw std::invalid_argument("Error: File Not Found.");

    hFile.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
    std::size_t Length = hFile.tellg();
    hFile.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
    std::vector<std::uint8_t> FileInfo(Length);
    hFile.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(FileInfo.data()), 54);

    if(FileInfo[0] != 'B' && FileInfo[1] != 'M')
    {
        hFile.close();
        throw std::invalid_argument("Error: Invalid File Format. Bitmap Required.");
    }

    if (FileInfo[28] != 24 && FileInfo[28] != 32)
    {
        hFile.close();
        throw std::invalid_argument("Error: Invalid File Format. 24 or 32 bit Image Required.");
    }

    BitsPerPixel = FileInfo[28];
    width = FileInfo[18] + (FileInfo[19] << 8);
    height = FileInfo[22] + (FileInfo[23] << 8);
    std::uint32_t PixelsOffset = FileInfo[10] + (FileInfo[11] << 8);
    std::uint32_t size = ((width * BitsPerPixel + 31) / 32) * 4 * height;
    Pixels.resize(size);

    hFile.seekg (PixelsOffset, std::ios::beg);
    hFile.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(Pixels.data()), size);
    hFile.close();
}

int main()
{
    BMP info = BMP("C:/Users/....../Desktop/SomeBmp.bmp");

    GLuint texture = 0;
    glGenTextures(1, &texture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, info.HasAlphaChannel() ? GL_RGBA : GL_RGB, info.GetWidth(), info.GetWidth(), 0, info.HasAlphaChannel() ? GL_BGRA : GL_BGR, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, info.GetPixels().data());
}
```

TGA's:

```
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>

#ifdef __APPLE__
#include <OpenGL/gl.h>
#include <OpenGL/glu.h>
#endif


#ifdef _WIN32
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glu.h>
#endif

typedef union PixelInfo
{
    std::uint32_t Colour;
    struct
    {
        std::uint8_t R, G, B, A;
    };
} *PPixelInfo;

class Tga
{
private:
    std::vector<std::uint8_t> Pixels;
    bool ImageCompressed;
    std::uint32_t width, height, size, BitsPerPixel;

public:
    Tga(const char* FilePath);
    std::vector<std::uint8_t> GetPixels() {return this->Pixels;}
    std::uint32_t GetWidth() const {return this->width;}
    std::uint32_t GetHeight() const {return this->height;}
    bool HasAlphaChannel() {return BitsPerPixel == 32;}
};

Tga::Tga(const char* FilePath)
{
    std::fstream hFile(FilePath, std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
    if (!hFile.is_open()){throw std::invalid_argument("File Not Found.");}

    std::uint8_t Header[18] = {0};
    std::vector<std::uint8_t> ImageData;
    static std::uint8_t DeCompressed[12] = {0x0, 0x0, 0x2, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0};
    static std::uint8_t IsCompressed[12] = {0x0, 0x0, 0xA, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0};

    hFile.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&Header), sizeof(Header));

    if (!std::memcmp(DeCompressed, &Header, sizeof(DeCompressed)))
    {
        BitsPerPixel = Header[16];
        width  = Header[13] * 256 + Header[12];
        height = Header[15] * 256 + Header[14];
        size  = ((width * BitsPerPixel + 31) / 32) * 4 * height;

        if ((BitsPerPixel != 24) && (BitsPerPixel != 32))
        {
            hFile.close();
            throw std::invalid_argument("Invalid File Format. Required: 24 or 32 Bit Image.");
        }

        ImageData.resize(size);
        ImageCompressed = false;
        hFile.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(ImageData.data()), size);
    }
    else if (!std::memcmp(IsCompressed, &Header, sizeof(IsCompressed)))
    {
        BitsPerPixel = Header[16];
        width  = Header[13] * 256 + Header[12];
        height = Header[15] * 256 + Header[14];
        size  = ((width * BitsPerPixel + 31) / 32) * 4 * height;

        if ((BitsPerPixel != 24) && (BitsPerPixel != 32))
        {
            hFile.close();
            throw std::invalid_argument("Invalid File Format. Required: 24 or 32 Bit Image.");
        }

        PixelInfo Pixel = {0};
        int CurrentByte = 0;
        std::size_t CurrentPixel = 0;
        ImageCompressed = true;
        std::uint8_t ChunkHeader = {0};
        int BytesPerPixel = (BitsPerPixel / 8);
        ImageData.resize(width * height * sizeof(PixelInfo));

        do
        {
            hFile.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&ChunkHeader), sizeof(ChunkHeader));

            if(ChunkHeader < 128)
            {
                ++ChunkHeader;
                for(int I = 0; I < ChunkHeader; ++I, ++CurrentPixel)
                {
                    hFile.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&Pixel), BytesPerPixel);

                    ImageData[CurrentByte++] = Pixel.B;
                    ImageData[CurrentByte++] = Pixel.G;
                    ImageData[CurrentByte++] = Pixel.R;
                    if (BitsPerPixel > 24) ImageData[CurrentByte++] = Pixel.A;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ChunkHeader -= 127;
                hFile.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&Pixel), BytesPerPixel);

                for(int I = 0; I < ChunkHeader; ++I, ++CurrentPixel)
                {
                    ImageData[CurrentByte++] = Pixel.B;
                    ImageData[CurrentByte++] = Pixel.G;
                    ImageData[CurrentByte++] = Pixel.R;
                    if (BitsPerPixel > 24) ImageData[CurrentByte++] = Pixel.A;
                }
            }
        } while(CurrentPixel < (width * height));
    }
    else
    {
        hFile.close();
        throw std::invalid_argument("Invalid File Format. Required: 24 or 32 Bit TGA File.");
    }

    hFile.close();
    this->Pixels = ImageData;
}


int main()
{
    Tga info = Tga("C:/Users/...../Desktop/SomeTGA.tga");

    GLuint texture = 0;
    glGenTextures(1, &texture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, info.HasAlphaChannel() ? GL_RGBA : GL_RGB, info.GetWidth(), info.GetWidth(), 0, info.HasAlphaChannel() ? GL_RGBA : GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, info.GetPixels().data());

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your code, but what does RGB mean in line RGB Pixel = {0};  did you mean struct RGBA ? Can you provide the whole class file in githup to help more people?

Comment: @wangdq Fixed. Added headers as well.

Comment: The TGA one is off for the width and height. It should multiply by 256 not 255 (0xFF)
width = Header[13] * 256 + Header[12];
height = Header[15] * 256 + Header[14];

Comment: How to get RGB colors (individually) for each pixel from Pixels.data() for BMP?

Comment: @Rounaq_intel;  You can do:  `reinterpret_cast<PixelInfo*>(Pixels.data())`  Note: BMP is BGRA and TGA is RGBA.

Comment: glGenTextures is deprecated.

Answer (score 6):

I interpreted this question as: "How do I load a TGA file? What I tried didn't work."

99% of the time the right answer is not going to be "copy and paste this function that loads TGA files which I wrote". That is the approach that the accepted answer is taking. But if you want a solution that not only works, but will be more maintainable and more likely to be fixed if it contains bugs, then it is better to use a library. Rolling your own solution is a fine way to learn and should be encouraged, but it is not usually the best or easiest way to get something done.

Use a real image library instead of trying to roll your own function to read them. Your assumptions on the data format are not correct, so the data you are getting is bunk. You appear to be assuming that the data is a 128x128 pixel raw.

**http://tgalib.sourceforge.net/** is an open source library for reading TGA files. Use it, for example.

**https://github.com/nothings/stb** is another alternative with a more liberal (public domain) license that in addition to loading TGA files has a lot of other things that would come in handy for OpenGL programs.

Both libraries are a better choice than copy-pasting code you found online.