# Any solution for TGA format loading in OpenCV4

Tags: opencv, tga, stb-image

There's no support TGA format for OpenCV currently.

And I know there's a single header file library named [stb_image](https://github.com/nothings/stb/blob/master/stb_image.h) that allow you to read/write TGA image.
But the use case with OpenCV on the Internet are so few. (more often to see people use it with OpenGL)

The second method I found.
There's a short code included (the answer) in this topic:
[Loading a tga/bmp file in C++/OpenGL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20595340/loading-a-tga-bmp-file-in-c-opengl)

Someone use this code to read TGA file into cv::Mat just like the code below.

```
Tga tgaImg = Tga("/tmp/test.tga");
Mat img(tgaImg.GetHeight(), tgaImg.GetWidth(), CV_8UC4);
memcpy(img.data, tgaImg.GetPixels().data(), tgaImg.GetHeight() * tgaImg.GetWidth() * 4);
```

But this is only for reading part. I wonder if stb_image can do the same thing like the code above. I mean the image data structure might be different. (not look into them yet)

I would like to ask people who also experience this before. Since DDS/TGA image format are also popular using in game texture, there must be people have already found the way. I mean read/write TGA format in OpenCV code.

Thanks.

Comment: For saving opencv image in tga use stbi_write_tga. This function takes pointer to image data as argument, which is img.data in case of cv::Mat type.

Comment: @Hihikomori Okay, going to try it now. Thanks.

Comment: @Hihikomori stbi_write_tga("export.tga", img.size().width, img.size().height, 0, img.data); right? the exported file size is so tiny and not able to view...weird. Code itself run without error.

Comment: @Hihikomori It works, I thought the 4th argument is for RLE flag. It is actually channel amount. And export well after I modify it to 4. Just need some BGR to RGB fix. Would you post it as answer? I want to set you as answer. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For saving opencv image in tga use stbi_write_tga. This function takes pointer to image data as argument, which is img.data in case of cv::Mat type.