# How to collect the 4 bytes of data per pixel in a BMP fast and effcicient and assemble them into a struct?

Tags: c++, methods, pixel, bmp

i have found this [Loading a tga/bmp file in C++/OpenGL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20595340/loading-a-tga-bmp-file-in-c-opengl), it works flawless and would like to use it in my project. however my project requires a RGB struct to modify the pixels buffer.

```
glDrawPixels(win_height, win_width, GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, myBuffer);
```

it needs some changes to make it work in my project.

```
typedef union PixelInfo
{
    std::uint32_t Colour;
    struct
    {
        float b, g, r, a;
    };
} *PPixelInfo;


class BMP
{
private:
    std::uint32_t width, height;
    std::uint16_t BitsPerPixel;
    std::vector<std::uint8_t> Pixels;

public:
    BMP(const char* FilePath);
    std::vector<std::uint8_t> GetPixels() const {return this->Pixels;}
    std::uint32_t GetWidth() const {return this->width;}
    std::uint32_t GetHeight() const {return this->height;}
    bool HasAlphaChannel() {return BitsPerPixel == 32;}
};

BMP::BMP(const char* FilePath)
{
    std::fstream hFile(FilePath, std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
    if (!hFile.is_open()) throw std::invalid_argument("Error: File Not Found.");

    hFile.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
    std::size_t Length = hFile.tellg();
    hFile.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
    std::vector<std::uint8_t> FileInfo(Length);
    hFile.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(FileInfo.data()), 54);

    if(FileInfo[0] != 'B' && FileInfo[1] != 'M')
    {
        hFile.close();
        throw std::invalid_argument("Error: Invalid File Format. Bitmap Required.");
    }

    if (FileInfo[28] != 24 && FileInfo[28] != 32)
    {
        hFile.close();
        throw std::invalid_argument("Error: Invalid File Format. 24 or 32 bit Image Required.");
    }

    BitsPerPixel = FileInfo[28];
    width = FileInfo[18] + (FileInfo[19] << 8);
    height = FileInfo[22] + (FileInfo[23] << 8);
    std::uint32_t PixelsOffset = FileInfo[10] + (FileInfo[11] << 8);
    std::uint32_t size = ((width * BitsPerPixel + 31) / 32) * 4 * height;
    Pixels.resize(size);

    hFile.seekg (PixelsOffset, std::ios::beg);
    hFile.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(Pixels.data()), size);
    hFile.close();
}

int main()
{
    BMP info = BMP("Fixedsys16x28.bmp");

    //info.
    std::cout << "getwidth: " << info.GetWidth() << endl;
    std::cout << "getheight: " << info.GetHeight()<< endl;

//    for(auto i : info.GetPixels()){
//        //float i_float = float(i);
//        //float res = i_float / 15.0;
//        //std::cout << std::hex << (int)i << " " << endl;
//        std::cout << setprecision(2) << fixed << (float) i / 255 << " " << endl;
//    }
    std::cout << endl;

    std::cout << "size: " << info.GetPixels().size() << endl;
    std::cout << "alpha: " << info.HasAlphaChannel() << endl;

    std::cout << setprecision(2) << fixed;
    for(int i = 0; i < static_cast<int>(info.GetPixels().size()); i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
            if(j == 0){
                std::cout << (float) info.GetPixels()[i]/ 255 << " ";
            }
            else if(j == 1){
                std::cout  << (float) info.GetPixels()[i] / 255 << " ";
            }
            else{
                std::cout << (float) info.GetPixels()[i] / 255;
            }
        }
        std::cout << endl;
    }

    getchar();

    GLuint texture = 0;
    glGenTextures(1, &texture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, info.HasAlphaChannel() ? GL_RGBA : GL_RGB, info.GetWidth(), info.GetWidth(), 0, info.HasAlphaChannel() ? GL_BGRA : GL_BGR, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, info.GetPixels().data());
}
```

how to change this line of code?

```
hFile.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(Pixels.data()), size);
```

so that vector gets filed with ...

```
typedef union PixelInfo
{
    std::uint32_t Colour;
    struct
    {
        float B, G, R, A;
    };
} *PPixelInfo;
```

collections.

after changing the setup of vector off course or use another.
what kind of of method / function, could replace `Pixels.data()` , so it collect these 4 bytes and assembles them accordingly in the type of struct `PixelInfo`?

since `Pixels.data()` basically provide a pointer to the pixel vector.
how does a method that can perform the requested task look like?
collect 4 bytes of data and format them accordingly and put them in a `vector<PixelInfo>` **while converting** "std::uint8_t" into float. fast and efficiently.

it should take this in consideration "info.HasAlphaChannel()".

the accompanied image data is:
[image: char array]
512×84 and the pixel vector size is "129024".
43008×3 bytes = 129024.

i made this loop on the pixel vector:

```
std::cout << setprecision(2) << fixed;
for(int i = 0; i < static_cast<int>(info.GetPixels().size()); i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
        if(j == 0){
            std::cout << (float) info.GetPixels()[i]/ 255 << " ";
        }
        else if(j == 1){
            std::cout  << (float) info.GetPixels()[i] / 255 << " ";
        }
        else{
            std::cout << (float) info.GetPixels()[i] / 255;
        }
    }
    std::cout << endl;
}
```

it seams to have worked correctly and even the last line contains 3 "bytes" of data.

this routine takes, like 20 seconds for an image 400 x 400 px.

```
vector<PixelInfo> pixelStore (info->GetPixels().size() / 3);
int counter = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < size; i+=3){
    PixelInfo temp;
    temp.r = 0;
    temp.g = 0;
    temp.b = 0;
    for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
        if(j == 0){
            temp.r = info->GetPixels()[i + j];
        }
        else if(j == 1){
            temp.g = info->GetPixels()[i + j];
        }
        else{
            temp.b = info->GetPixels()[i + j];
        }

        if(j == 2){
            //pixelStore.push_back(temp);
            pixelStore[counter] = temp;
            counter++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the `union PixelInfo` type you defined there simply doesn't make much sense. What do you need that absurd construct for? Either store your pixel data as 8bit per channel uint, or as 32bit per channel float (and convert accordingly).

Comment: how to do that? that's how i started my project using this union.
now I'm including files from this project and it has this file: https://github.com/planetchili/chili_framework/blob/master/Engine/Colors.h, but when trying to use it, it crashed because OpenGL in contrary to DirectX uses Float. obliviously it would be much faster storing info a word ''unsigned int dword;''. how it's done?

Comment: OpenGL doesn't require float formats for pixel data, quite the contrary, unsigned byte is the usual format there and you shouldn't use float unless you need the precision

Comment: Look at the translation loops. The outer loop will iterate byte-by-byte through the `vector` of bytes. So what's the point of the inner loop? It looks like it processes each byte in the `vector` three times. Not what you want to do. Ditch the loop and turn `j` into a simple counter. Print each value and when `j` hits three, reset it and start a new line.

Comment: Or divide size by 3 and read three bytes at a time. Probably easier.

Comment: what about this line " glDrawPixels(win_height, win_width, GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, myBuffer); ? i converted the union to "std::uint8_t", changed the values and now it chrashes.

Comment: @derhass  ok, i change it "glDrawPixels(win_height, win_width, GL_RGB, GL_INT, myBuffer);" and it works again.

Comment: @user4581301, that's a side project to see if the BMP load code worked, before i incluided it to my project and i wanted to see if it matches with 3 bytes on the image added to this "article".

Answer (score 0):

Your code shows `std::vector<std::uint8_t> Pixels;` which is a sequence of 8-bit pixels I suppose.  You want a vector of `PixelInfo` instead?  Now does that structure match the format of bytes in the file?  If that's the case, then what's the problem?
If the bytes in the file match the layout of your structure (including the machine's Endian!) just do it the same way:

```
vector<PixelInfo> Pixels;
size_t pixels_to_read = ....??? ;
Pixels.resize(pixels_to_read);
hFile.read (reinterpret_cast<char*>(Pixels.data()), pixels_to_read*sizeof(PixelInfo));
```

## update

> collect 4 bytes of data and format them accordingly and put them in a vector while converting "std::uint8_t" into float. fast and efficiently.

```
std::byte buf[4];
hFile.read (reinterpret_cast<char*>(buf),4);  // read 4 bytes from file
PixelInfo px;
px.R = buf[0];  // converts 8-bit integer to float
px.G = buf[1];
px.B = buf[2];
px.A = buf[3];
```

Note that your `PixelInfo` union doesn't make sense -- how does the 32-bit color match the layout of the 4 32-bit components?  Furthermore, I don't think that definition is legal, as there is no such thing as an anonymous struct.  If that compiles, it must be a compiler extension.

As for doing it *fast* :
Read in a lot at a time, rather than one pixel.  A whole row is good, if it's not practical to read the entire file into memory.  Then you just step along the buffer you had loaded.

You can hope that the 4 individual statements get auto-vectorized by the optimizer.  If you have a tight and simple loop around just that part (to process a whole row) you might get the compiler to vectorize it.

The fact that you have to write 4 separate statements because the left hand side uses different names rather than an index should not affect the overall speed.

20 seconds for a 400×400 pixel image?  I would think it would be instantaneous.  I have experience loading/converting/decoding graphics files, having written a library for DOS and bare metal (16-bit x86 code) back in the early '90's.  You might try benchmarking code that *only* does this conversion listed above, to see if that's your bottleneck or not.  Look at the code generated (in the debugger, or using Compiler Explorer) to see if it's vectorizing.  Look into calling the vector primitives intrinsic instructions directly, if your compiler has that available.  See if you're using all the right compiler optimization flags.

Comment: i would like to have some sort off function for: "hFile.read (reinterpret_cast<char*>(Pixels.data()), pixels_to_read*sizeof(PixelInfo));" to replace the pointer to: Pixels.data()), gather 3 or 4 bytes (depending if alpha is present) of data and assemble them into a vector of RGBA structure, currently i have another method below this class, looping the vector: Pixels and assemble them in a vector of type RGBA structures:  PixelStore and it takes 20 seconds for a 400 x 400 pixel bitmap file. wondering if this can be done much faster.

Comment: ok, the padding issue is solved, i added some code to show you what i mean, i want to know if it possible to do this faster than 20 seconds for a 400 x 400 px BMP image.